# Existence of a Global Trivialization of Pullback Bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles

Good evening!

Let us assume that we have a $n$-dimensional compact Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, and a smooth cylinder $u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{S}^1,M), (s,t)\longmapsto u(s,t)$. My question then is: Can the pullback tangent bundle $u^* TM$ always be globally trivialized along $u$?

I would argue as follows: Take any point $(s_0,t_0)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{S}^1$, and define a local orthonormal basis $(Z_1(s_0,t_0),...,Z_n(s_0,t_0))$ of $T_{u(s_0,t_0)}M$. Then, via parallel transport (w.r.t. the Levi-Civita connection) along $t\longmapsto u(s_0,t)$, one gets an orthonormal basis $(Z_1(s_0,t),...,Z_n(s_0,t))$ of $T_{u(s_0,t)}M$ for every $t\in\mathbb{S}^1$ (since parallel transport leaves $g(Z_i(t),Z_j(t))$ constant) that depends smoothly on $t$.
Now, to reach the other values of $s\in\mathbb{R}$, one parallel transports (for fixed $t\in\mathbb{S}^1$)the basis  $(Z_1(s_0,t),...,Z_n(s_0,t))$ along $s\longmapsto u(s,t)$.

Thus, the map $\Theta:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow u^*TM, \Theta(s,t)e_i = Z_i(s,t)$ (where $(e_1,...,e_n)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$) is a global trivialization of $u^*TM$.

Of course, this gets difficult if $u$ intersects itself at some point (i.e. $u(s,t)=u(s',t')$ for $(s,t)\neq(s',t')$), since then one would have two different trivializations for $T_{u(s,t)} = T_{u(s',t')}$. However, I am not sure how big of a problem this is, since the map $(s,t)\longmapsto (Z_1(s,t),...,Z_n(s,t))$ should still be well-defined.

I would like to know what has to be corrected to make this rigorous, or what additional assumptions I should put on $M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions about the triviality of bundles are typically answered in the language of algebraic topology, so I hope you are familiar with this terminology. I'll use the first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1\in H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}/2)$. Firstly, we can deformation retract the cylinder onto $S^1$ and then ask whether the pullback of a tangent bundle to $S^1$ is trivial (or not). Consider the embedding $u:S^1=\mathbb{RP}^1\to\mathbb{RP}^2$. We know that $w_1(T\mathbb{RP}^2)\neq 0$, i.e. $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is not orientable. By naturality, we have $w_1(u^*T\mathbb{RP}^2)=u^*w_1(T\mathbb{RP}^2)$.

Noting that the cohomology ring with $\mathbb{Z}/2$-coefficients for $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}/2[x]/(x^{n+1})$, the element $w_1(T\mathbb{RP}^2)\in H^1(\mathbb{RP}^2,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ must be the generator $x$, which pulls back to the generator of the cohomology ring of $\mathbb{RP}^1$, and is thus also a non-trivial element. Consequently, $w_1(u^*T\mathbb{RP}^2)\neq 0$ which implies that $u^*T\mathbb{RP}^2$ is non-trivial.

On the other hand, if you consider maps $u:S^1\to M$ where $M$ is an orientable manifold, then $w_1(TM)=0$ and hence $w_1(u^*TM)=0$. Therefore, if $M$ is orientable, the pullback of its tangent bundle to a cylinder will always be trivial. This is because any vector bundle $E$ over $S^1$ with $w_1(E)=0$ can be trivialised. For a discussion of this fact, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37980/is-every-real-vector-bundle-over-the-circle-necessarily-trivial).

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. Can one say more about triviality of $u^*TM$ if $u(s,\cdot):\mathbb{S}^1\longrightarrow M, t\longmapsto u(s,t)$ can be extended to a map on the unit disc $\mathbb{D} = B_1(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. if $u$ is contractible?

Comment: If we suppose that the image of the extension $\widetilde{u}:\mathbb{D}\to M$ is a submanifold, then $\widetilde{u}^*TM$ is trivial. The bundle $u^*TM$ would be $\iota^*\widetilde{u}^*TM$ ($\iota:S^1\to\mathbb{D}$ the inclusion) and would then also be trivial, if we look at the Stiefel-Whitney class as I did in the answer. If the image is not a submanifold, I think it becomes a lot more tricky, and I don't think one can make a general statement in that case.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Do you have some recommendations on online ressources where I could deepen my knowledge about arguments like these?

Comment: Cohomology and characteristic classes are covered in textbooks on algebraic topology, such as Hatcher's book "Algebraic Topology". To learn about Stiefel-Whitney classes, one really needs this approach to cohomology, not just de Rham cohomology on smooth manifolds. The book "Geometry, Topology and Physics" by Nakahara also contains a more physics/geometry oriented discussion of these ideas. There's also a standard reference called "Characteristic Classes" by Stasheff and Milnor, but this source is rather outdated, for my tastes.

Comment: PS. I should add Hatcher's "K-theory" book to the list. It should be combined with his algebraic topology book. K-theory is the one which actually covers characteristic classes and vector bundles.

Comment: I wanted to clarify that if $u$ extends to $\tilde{u}$, then $u^\ast TM$ is trivial, independent of the image of $\tilde{u}$.  To see this, recall that for a reasonable space $X$, rank $n$-vector bundles are over it are classified by $[X,BO(n)]$, homotopy classes of maps into the classifying space $BO(n)$.  Suppose $\phi:M\rightarrow BO(n)$ classifies $TM$.  Then $u^\ast(TM)$ is classified by $\phi\circ u$.  If $u$ extends to $\tilde{u}$, then the map $u$ factors through the contractible space $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{D}$, so $\phi\circ u$ is homotopically trivial, so $u^\ast TM$ is trivial.